# HP ALM file attachment

Tags: java, attachment, multipart, rest-assured, alm

I am doing an API automation of hp-alm using REST assured in Java. I'm trying to upload an attachment to a created run instance.

```java
urlheaders.put("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
File file = new File("H:\\Desktop\\a.zip");
RequestSpecification httpRequest14 = RestAssured.given().headers(urlheaders).cookies(loginCookies).cookies(sessionCookies).multiPart( "file", file, "multipart/form-data");
Response attachment = httpRequest14.request(Method.POST,"/qcbin/rest/domains/d/projects/p/runs/13634/attachments");
String attachmentResponseBody = attachment.getBody().asString();
//logger.info("attachment Response Body is =>  " + attachmentResponseBody);
statusCode = attachment.getStatusCode();
logger.info("The attachment status code recieved: " + statusCode);
```

The status code is 500 and the error is:

> File name and content should be supplied.

What does the error mean? Can anyone tell whats wrong in my code?

```html
<div id="content-holder">
    <h1>File name and content should be supplied</h1>
    <div>
        <tr>
            <td><a id="exception-id-title">Exception Id:</a></td>
            <td>qccore.general-error</td>
        </tr>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is there any method other then using rest assured to get desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have incorrect multipart request, you need to provide at least two parts: one which contains the file name, and one which contains the file itself.

Or you can use `application/octet-stream Content-Type` instead.
See examples in the [official docs](https://admhelp.microfocus.com/alm/api_refs/REST_TECH_PREVIEW/Content/REST_API_Tech_Preview/REST/attachments_collection.html#multipart_form_data_example).

Edit: working code: `RestAssured.given().headers(urlheaders).cookies(loginCookies).cookies(sessionCookies).body(file);`
And urlheaders must contain:

- Content-Type = application/octet-stream
- Slug = file name

Comment: i have already gone through the official doc, but could not understand completely. With my understanding, i have written the above code. Can you plz elaborate on how to do it? Thank you

Comment: Haven't used RestAssured, but in general you need to pass 'Content-Type' header == 'application/octet-stream', 'Slug'== file name and put your file into request body

Comment: the file which i want to upload will consist of screenshot of AUT.and how to put file into body??    other than rest assured, how can we do the upload of attachment??

Comment: maybe, body(new File("..."))?

Comment: RequestSpecification httpRequest14 = RestAssured.given().headers(urlheaders).cookies(loginCookies).cookies(sessionCookies).multiPart( "file", file, "multipart/form-data").body(file);
 after making changes to the request as u said, now its giving 415 error code - Unsupported Media Type.
Any other methods to upload files, other than rest-assured

Comment: I think you missed my point, it's probably easier for you to prepare request with 'application/octet-stream' content-type (not a multipart), so it should be something like that: RestAssured.given().headers(urlheaders).cookies(loginCookies).cookies(sessionCookies).body(file);
and make sure your urlheaders contain: Content-Type = 'application/octet-stream' and 'Slug'=file.getName()

Comment: also, we are developing a commercial product for integration with ALM: https://www.agiletestware.com/bumblebee, so maybe you could try that instead of spending time on a custom solution

Comment: I would appreciate if you accept my answer since it is the correct one

Answer (score 0):

As advised by Sergi,
The solution is:

```
                    File file = new File(filePath);
                    urlheaders.put("slug", file.getName());
                    RequestSpecification httpRequest14 = RestAssured.given().headers(urlheaders).cookies(loginCookies).cookies(sessionCookies).body(file);
                    Response attachment = httpRequest14.request(Method.POST,"/qcbin/rest/domains/"+domain+"/projects/"+project+"/runs/"+stepID+"/attachments");
                    String attachmentResponseBody = attachment.getBody().asString();
                    logger.info("attachment Response Body is =>  " + attachmentResponseBody);
                    statusCode = attachment.getStatusCode();
                    logger.info("The attachment status code recieved: " + statusCode);

This will add the attachment to the run instance.
Thank You Sergi
```